# Spring: new() operator and autowired together

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

If I use Spring, which of these two methods is more correct.
Can I use the new() operator even if I use dipendency injection?.Can I mix both?
I would like to have some clarification on these concepts.
Thanks

First method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String create(Model model){
 model.addAttribute(new User());
 return "index";
}
```

Second Method:

```
@Autowired
User user;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String create(Model model){
 model.addAttribute(user);
 return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By using dependency injection does not mean that the use of `new` operator is automatically prohibited throughout your code.  It's just different approaches applied to different requirements.

A web application in spring is composed of a number of collaborating beans that are instantiated by the framework and (unless overriding the default scope) are singletons. This means that they must not preserve any state since they are shared across all requests (threads). In other words if you autowire the User object (or any other model attribute), it is created on application context initialization and the same instance is given to any user request. This also means that if a request modifies the object, other requests will see the modification as well. Needless to say this is erroneous behavior in multithreaded applications because your User object (or other model attribute) belongs to the request, so it must have the very narrow scope of a method invocation, or session at most.

You can also have spring create beans with different scopes for you, but for a simple scenario of a model attribute initialization, the `new` operator is sufficient. See the following documentation if interested in bean scopes : [Bean scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

So in your use case, the second method is totally wrong.
But you can also delegate the creation of your model attributes to spring **if they are used as command objects** (i.e. if you want to bind request parameters to them). Just add it in the method signature (with or without the modelattribute annotation).

So you may also write the above code as

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String create(@ModelAttribute User user){     
 return "index";
}
```

see also : [Supported method argument types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your beans to be "managed" by Spring (for e.g. to use with Dependency Injection  or PropertySources or any other Spring-related functionality), then you do NOT create new objects on your own. You declare them (via XML or JavaConfig) and let Spring create and manage them.

If the beans don't need to be "managed" by Spring, you can create a new instance using new operator.

In your case, is this particular object - User - used anywhere else in code? Is it being injected into any other Spring bean? Or is any other Spring bean being injected in User? How about any other Spring-based functionality?

If the answer to all these questions is "No", then you can use the first method (create a new object and return it). <strike>As soon as the create() method execution is complete, the User object created there would go out of scope and will be marked for GC.</strike> The User object created in this method will eventually be GC-ed.

Comment: Your last sentence is not correct. It's not "out of scope". The object is still referenced in the `Model` object referenced by `model`. It will eventually be transferred to the `HttpServletRequest` attributes. Only when the request handling cycle is done, and the container reclaims (or discards) the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` will the `User` object be a candidate for GC.

Comment: You might want to talk about using the second method with a prototype scope bean.

Comment: I thought about it but then it just makes the answer more complex, so I kept it out. Feel free to answer this question if you have a better way of explaining this.

Comment: I can use The @autowired annotation only outside the method because if i insert it inside the method i have some error.If the user object is used only inside the "create" method , how can i solve it?

Comment: in that case, I don't think you need the @autowire user object. Create and populate your object inside the create() method and you're done. If you want to post your source code on github, I could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Things can be injected in two ways in a Spring MVC applications. And yes, you can you can mix injection and creation if doing right.

Components like the controller in your example are singletons managed by the application context. If you inject anything to them it is global, not per request or session! So a user is not the right thing to inject, a user directory can be. Be aware of this as you are writing a multithreaded application!

Request related things can be injected to the method like the used locale, the request, the user principal may be injected as parameters, see a full list at [Spring MVC Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments).

But if you create a model attribute you may use new() to create it from scratch. I will not be filled by spring but to be used by your view to display data created by the controller. When created in the request mapped method that is ok.